# Cannot create 2D-Array string[][] in function

Tags: arrays, string

I'm trying to create a 2D string array to serialize my struct, which is:

```
struct Submission {
    uint256 id;
    address creator;
    string title;
    string IPFS_CID;
    uint16 likeCount;
    uint16 dislikeCount;
    mapping(address => uint256) likes;
    mapping(address => uint256) dislikes;
}
```

With the import of

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
function getLastNSubmissions(uint128 n) public view returns (string[][] memory) {
    require((n-1) > 0, "Cannot get more submissions than available.");

    string[][6] memory returnSubmissions;
    uint start = submissionId - n;
    uint pos = 0;

    for (uint i=start; i < submissionId; i+=1) {
        Submission storage s = submissions[i];

        returnSubmissions[pos] = [
            Strings.toString(s.id), 
            abi.encodePacked(s.creator), 
            s.title, 
            s.IPFS_CID, 
            Strings.toString(s.likeCount), 
            Strings.toString(s.dislikeCount)
        ];
    }
}
```

At
`returnSubmissions[Strings.toString(pos)] = new string[Strings.toString(s.id), ...]`

I get the linting error of:

```
Expected ']' but got ','
```

Can someone help fixing this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who'll stumble upon the same issue on day: This is how my function ended up working:

```
/*
* Will return the last n submissions in serialized form: [n...][id, creator, title, CID, likeCount, dislikeCount]
*/
function getLastNSubmissions(uint256 n) public view returns (string[6][] memory) {
    require(submissionId > 0, "There are no submissions yet.");

    string[6][] memory returnSubmissions = new string[6][](n);

    uint start = submissionId - n;
    uint pos = 0;

    for (uint i=start; i < submissionId; i+=1) {
        Submission storage s = submissions[i];

        returnSubmissions[pos][0] = Strings.toString(s.id);
        returnSubmissions[pos][1] = Strings.toHexString(uint160(s.creator), 20);
        returnSubmissions[pos][2] = s.title;
        returnSubmissions[pos][3] = s.IPFS_CID;
        returnSubmissions[pos][4] = Strings.toString(s.likeCount);
        returnSubmissions[pos][5] = Strings.toString(s.dislikeCount);

        pos += 1;
    }
    return returnSubmissions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to define the length of at least one array.

See this:

"Defining Two-Dimensional arrays
In Solidity, the notation of multidimensional array is reversed ONLY WHEN DEFINING compared to other programming languages.

For this case, we are going to compare 2 arrays:

string[2][] crypto_names;

string[][6] names_A_to_F;

In the first example crypto_names , we have a dynamic array outright, but its elements are arrays of fixed size (2). In the second case, names_A_to_F is a fixed-size array which has 6 elements, each of which is a dynamic array
"
from [link](https://jeancvllr.medium.com/solidity-tutorial-all-about-array-efdff4613694)